# Issues with god and init script

Tags: ruby, thin, god

I am monitoring a thin server with god.
If I run god from the command line as:

```
god -c /path/to/config
```

Then things work.

If, however, I start god using an init script as:

```
/etc/init.d/god start
```

things don't work. God complains that the script exited with a non-zero exit code.

My init script is here:

https://gist.github.com/e99a3dd703d8cfda5d0b

Any idea what might be the issue? Is there a problem with the init file?